# Timeseries plot in R with 2 variables

Tags: r

I Have this dataset where i would like to plot a time series of score1 and score2 in R. May I know how could i achieve that?

```
DT                 Score1  Score2
12-01-21 1:30        1       4
12-02-22 1:30        5       4
12-12-21 1:30        1       4
01-01-22 12:30       0       3
03-02-22 1:00        3       1
03-02-22 1:14        4       1
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Can you instead use `dput(your_dataset)` to communicate your data set?

Answer (score 0):

Using `plot()` and `points()`

```
plot(df$Score1 ~ df$DT)
points(df$Score1 ~ df$DT)
```

A little more tweaking to make it a bit nicer... there's so much more you can do

```
plot(df$Score1 ~ df$DT, typ="l", col="black", 
     xlab="Date", ylab="Score")
points(df$Score1 ~ df$DT, typ="l", col="red")
```

Or for a ggplot (`library(ggplot2)`) version (again, much tweaking is possible)

```
data1 %>%
  ggplot(mapping=aes(x=DT, y=Score1)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_line(y=data1$Score2, col="red")
```

Answer (score 0):

I separated the `date` from the `time` and created  a plot based on `time` variable using `geom_line()` and `geom_step()`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

data <-data.frame("DT"=c("12-01-21", "12-02-22", "12-12-21", "01-01-22", "03-02-22", "03-02-22"), 
                   "time"=c("1:30","1:30","1:30","12:30","1:00","1:14"),
                   "Score 1"=c(1,5,1,0,3,4),
                   "Score 2" =c (4,4,4,3,1,1))


df<-melt(data)

(plot<-ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=value, group=variable)) +  
    geom_line(aes(color=variable), size=1)+theme_bw()) # the case of geom_step() is  geom_step(aes(color=variable), size=1)
```

**geom_line()**
[image]

**geom_steps()**

[image]

And `facet_wrap` based on **DT variable**

```
(plot<-ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=value, group=variable)) +  
    geom_line(aes(color=variable), size=1)+theme_bw()+
  facet_wrap(~DT))
```

[image]